# I want to know why my Magento Module with only controllers is not working

Tags: magento, module, controllers

**This is my activation file, 
    in app/etc/modules/My_Test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**This is my config file in app/code/local/MY/Test/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>

        <helpers>
            <my_test>
                <class>My_Test_Helper</class>
            </my_test>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mytest>
                <class>My_Test_Model</class>
            </my_test>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <my_test>
                <class>My_Test_Block</class>
            </my_test>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <my_test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </my_test>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

**This is my controllers code
in app/core/local/My/Test/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class My_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "This is the Module MyTest";
    }
}
```

Now when i am giving the url
 176.58.99.99/herbal/index.php/test/index/index
 176.58.99.99/herbal/index.php/test/
 176.58.99.99/herbal/test/index/index
 176.58.99.99/herbal/test/

Its showing 404 error

Comment: Are you aware that the opening and closing tag in your model section differ (`mytest` vs. `my_test`), or is this just a copy/paste error?

Comment: Also you stated your file is in location MY/Test <-- Magento will fail to load classes on a unix based ststem if the Case isn't correct, MY isn't the same as My

Comment: The typo above would cause issues as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You say your controller is located in `app/core/local/My/Test/controllers/IndexController.php` while it should be placed as followed: `app/code/local/My/Test/controllers/IndexController.php`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case it was about file permissions. Make sure that your files and directories have the proper access permissions, if not, magento will never be able to read those files.